# mySQL insert just won't work, but will with other table

Tags: php, mysql, database, web-applications

I have a mySQL issue that has me stumped for hours!

Context: I am creating a web-application to teach children different musical symbols on touch devices

Problem: after running this individual script, no row is created although last echo argument works.

Wierd: this is modeled after other scripts I have working.

EDIT: I will re-furnish the code with prepared statements after we find the problem.

Here is the code:

```
<?php

$database_connect = mysql_connect('localhost','ragstudi','*****');

if (!$database_connect) {die ('Not connected to SQL' . mysql_error());};

mysql_select_db('ragstudi_musicGameScores') or die ('db doesnt exist');


$userName = "Jimmy";//$_POST["username"];
$gameLevel = 1;//$_POST["level"];
$gameScore = 2300;//$_POST["score"];
$userGroup = "RagWway";

$highScores = mysql_query("INSERT INTO highScores (name, groupBy, level, score) values('".$userName."','".$userGroup."','".$gameLevel."','".$gameScore."')");
if (!$highScores){
    die(
        mysql_error()
        )
};
```

The database _musicGameScores is set up like this
Id, primary, auto increment, integer
name, varchar
groupBy, varchar
level, integer
score, integer

The password is Star'ed out. Thank you all in advance!

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: Thank you for this. I have not dealt with a lot of mySQL yet, but when I first did, it was not this way. I will implement this after this issue is resolved. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GROUP` is a reserved keyword. You must properly escape it so it will not generate an error.

```
INSERT INTO highScores (id, user, `group`, level, score) VALUES(...)
```

- [MySQL Reserved Keywords List](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with [`SQL Injection`](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value(*s*)  of the variables came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: It won't generate an error because the OP is not using error handlers.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO how about the server? Will it allow the query to be inserted when it has a syntax error?

Comment: We don't know if `error_reporting` is enabled.

Comment: I was unaware that mysql_ is now deprecated. I will look into the implementation of mysqli. However the escape did not work. Thank you for your time in helping me sort this out.

Comment: after the line of `mysql_qery(...)`, add this line `if (!$highScores){die(mysql_error())};` to see what is the error and post it here.

Comment: the log says [04-Apr-2013 19:16:19] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '}' in /home2/ragstudi/public_html/game/wp-content/themes/responsive/php/saveScores.php on line 19. In my code, this is error handler line.

Comment: the entire code is posted in my OP. The date is from the error log.

Comment: is column `ID` auto_incremented?

Comment: Yes, it is auto incremented.

Comment: pass `null` value on it or remove `ID` from the statement, eg `INSERT INTO(name, groupBy, level, score) VALUES (....)`

Comment: Still no luck. I updated the code in the op to reflect what it is now. Once again thank you for all your time and effort!

Comment: @JW I also updated to show the table layout.

Comment: the Column Name was the reason it wasn't working. Thanks! "Name" should be put on that list then, because it was not.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add **``** in every column, maybe theres a reserve keyword out there.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO highScores (`id`, `user`, `group`, `level`, `score`) values('','".$userName."','".$userGroup."','".$gameLevel."','".$gameScore."')");
```

Comment: This answer does not add anything new; further you don't need backticks around every column.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO did see J W answer while posting this.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this. Cheers! :D

$highScores = mysql_query("INSERT INTO highScores (id, user, `group`, level, score) values('','".$userName."','".$userGroup."','".$gameLevel."','".$gameScore."')");